# Express JS, Load handlebar partial via JQuery AJAX call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js, handlebars.js

I have been using handlebars as template engine for my express app:

```
app.engine('handlebars', handlebars({defaultLayout: 'main'}));
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');
app.use(express.static('assets'));
```

I have created my partial in `/views/partials/my_partial.handlebars`:

```
{{#each questions}}
<form class='questions-form' id='form{{id}}'> <p class='question'> {{question}}</p>
    <input type='hidden' name='questionId' value='{{id}}'/>
    <p>Hello</p>
</form>
{{/each}}
```

I want to load this partial only after Jquery finishes leading it's data via AJAX call:

```
$.getJSON( "/user, function( data ) {
   var questions = Handlebars.partials['my_partial'];
    questionBlock.html(questions(data));
}
```

However, when my AJAX request finishes, my browser shows me this error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Handlebars is not defined
```

Why this is happening?

Comment: Where do you define `Handlebars` in your jQuery?

Comment: @ItsGreg Do I need to add script tag in my layouts header? Is there another way to dynamically load partials via ajax calls?

Comment: @Mr.D yes you do need to add a tag script to load handlebars.js file before you can use it.